# Adding a third layer on my dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, hover, dropdown

I have dropdown menu with two levels but want to add a third level. Can you help me alter the code such that the third level menu hovers by the right?

Here's my CSS:

```
    #menu-bar {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 6px 6px 4px 6px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
  background: #C7C7C7;
  border: solid 0px #6D6D6D;
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
}
#menu-bar li {
  margin: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
#menu-bar a {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #363434;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
}
#menu-bar li ul li a {
  margin: 0;
}
#menu-bar .active a, #menu-bar li:hover > a {
  background: #424242;
  color: #E6E6E6;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul li:hover a, #menu-bar li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #666;
  -box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
#menu-bar ul a:hover {
  background: #4D4D4D !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu-bar ul {
  background: #DDDDDD;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left: 0;
  border: solid 1px #B4B4B4;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
}
#menu-bar ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu-bar ul a {
  padding:10px 0px 10px 15px;
  color:#424242 !important;
  font-size:14px;
  font-style:normal;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 7px;
}
#menu-bar ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 7px;
}

#menu-bar:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu-bar {
  display: inline-block;
}
  html[xmlns] #menu-bar {
  display: block;
}
* html #menu-bar {
  height: 1%;
}
```

Here's my html code:

```
<ul id="menu-bar">
 <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Travel ▿</a></a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Philippines ▹</a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Bacolod</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grids</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frameworks</a></li>
        </ul>
   </li>

   <li><a href="#">Asia ▹</a></li>
   <li><hr><li>
   <li><a href="#">Travelogue</a></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Life Lately</a>
 <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact ▿</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Send a Message</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Archive</a></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Press</a></a></li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want to have your third menu on the right side of the first? if i'm right thats what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Please close html tags properly as they started. (I have done proper tags closing in my answer)

```
#menu-bar ul > li > ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

This class is added for third level menu

```css
#menu-bar {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 6px 6px 4px 6px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
  background: #C7C7C7;
  border: solid 0px #6D6D6D;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

#menu-bar li {
  margin: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu-bar a {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #363434;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
}

#menu-bar li ul li a {
  margin: 0;
}

#menu-bar .active a,
#menu-bar li:hover>a {
  background: #424242;
  color: #E6E6E6;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
}

#menu-bar ul li:hover a,
#menu-bar li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #666;
  -box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}

#menu-bar ul a:hover {
  background: #4D4D4D !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
}

#menu-bar li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#menu-bar ul {
  background: #DDDDDD;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left: 0;
  border: solid 1px #B4B4B4;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
}

#menu-bar ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu-bar ul a {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 15px;
  color: #424242 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
}

#menu-bar ul li:first-child>a {
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 7px;
}

#menu-bar ul li:last-child>a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 7px;
}

#menu-bar:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#menu-bar {
  display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] #menu-bar {
  display: block;
}

* html #menu-bar {
  height: 1%;
}

/* For Third Level Menu */
#menu-bar ul>li>ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Third Level Menu</title>
</head>

<body>

  <ul id="menu-bar">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Travel ▿</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Philippines ▹</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Bacolod</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Grids</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Frameworks</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Asia ▹</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">India</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">China</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shrilanka</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <hr>
          <li><a href="#">Travelogue</a></li>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Life Lately</a>
        <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
        <!-- <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact ▿</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Send a Message</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li> -->
      </li>
    </li>
  </ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Commented some menu for proper demo in snippet

Comment: Thanks, Rahul! However, is there a way I can align the div to the center? It's currently aligned to the right and I want it to be put in the middle of the page. I tried using margin: 0 auto on #menu-bar a { but it doesn't help.